# Write H.264 bit-stream to ts using C++

Tags: c++, h.264

How can I write H.264 bit stream to ts file without any library(like ffmpeg)? Well, 4B for header(containing Sync Byte, PID etc) and 184B for payload, but I want to go to detail, when this flags are to set, their values etc. I didn't find any source containing detail.

Comment: This is not a very easy to do. You'll need to parse the bitstream into NAL units, collect them into frames, pack each frame into PES frame, then pack PES frames into TS frames, add PAT and PMT tables, and PCR timestamps. Main standard for MPEG TS is ISO/IEC 13818-1, it covers most of the stuff you'll need to know.

Comment: many thanks. yes, I know this is not that easy. well, let me study as much as I can and 'll update if any problem

Comment: @AndreyTurkin  Well, I made some progress. Firstly, I wrote 4B header data(without the adaptation field) and assigned 01 to adaptation field control(indicating there is payload data only after header). Secondly, I appended 184B payload data with the header. So, my TS only has the PES data.
What next? do I have to add the PAT and PMT data also? Are these mandatory if I want to run a small portion of a TS data?

Comment: It depends on what you want to do. Chances are you have to add them; good thing is that you can probably make them as 2 TS packets worth of static data, and just add them once before any H264 data.